# In UWP, how do I gather data from one thread and process it on another? An issue of timing

Tags: c#, uwp, timing

This is an issue of somewhat tight timing that I'm trying to wrap my head around. My UWP app interfaces with some custom hardware through serial communication. It gathers approximately 164 kilobytes of data per second, which is tightly timed by the hardware at 10 bytes per 61 microseconds, therefore gathering all the data over 0.999424 seconds. This is so I can demodulate to extract certain quantities of interest.

The requirement of this is that I *must* space the data acquisition out over one second. For the platform I'm using, the demodulation algorithm takes about 200 milliseconds, and so until now I've been using a `DispatcherTimer` with an interval of 1250 ms. The event that it fires initiates communication with the hardware, listens until the specified buffer is full (for one second), then processes the data (up to 100 ms, approximately) then sits idle until the 1250 ms is over. Rinse and repeat.

The downside of this is data loss. Over 24 hours, I lose 17280 readings, and my timestamps get funky. I would like to clock one reading every second (within the realisms of computer timings).

I'm currently investigating using a `System.Threading.Timer` to fire my event every 1000 ms, and what I'd like to do is gather data in the `System.Threading.Timer` event, and process that data in the background while the next tick gathers a new batch?

I should note that I am limited to using UWP. I'm locked in to a Raspberry Pi running Windows IoT.

Comment: Your question is too broad. However, some points of interest: any timer running on Windows is going to have limited resolution. You will never get your code to run always exactly every 1000 ms. If your goal is to not lose any samples, it seems to me that the right thing to do is read data constantly (you can do this asynchronously with the `SerialPort` class), and then as you're buffering the data, use a `Stopwatch` to measure the elapsed time since the the current block of data started (reset the `Stopwatch` with each block), then hand the current block off to a different thread to process.

Comment: See `BlockingCollection<T>` for a managed-code built-in producer/consumer data structure.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm with you up to "then hand the current block off to a different thread to process"...do you have any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: _"do you have any suggestions on how to implement this?"_ -- See my previous comment. I would expect that class to work in your seemingly simple scenario, but you can also look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library, which has more features to simplify implementation of more complex scenarios.